# React.js - const in async becomes undefined

Tags: javascript

```
    const test = order.restaurantId;
    console.log(test); //here test == 3


    const getAvailableHours = async () =>{

        console.log(test); //test == undefined


        await fetch(`API Address`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(responseText => {
                console.log(responseText);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Hi, I am trying to fetch data from API by using restaurant ID but when I'm passing the ID to async it becomes undefined.
I am new in React.js, anyone has any ideas?

Comment: That seems impossible. Are you sure they are in the same context?

Answer (score 1):

async await syntax allows you to avoid .then method, so you can handle promises with a more readable syntax. With try catch blocks you can handle errors, try this:

```js
const getAvailableHours = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('https://api-address-goes-here/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        
        let responseText = await response.json();
        return responseText;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```